# Comparing attributes and assign a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, model-associations

This is the first time approaching something like this, so am looking for some advice/best practice to achieve my goal. I want to assign a value (score) to the result of a prediction made by a user..So in my case a user can make predictions on football fixtures, if they guess correctly then they get 3 points lets say.

So far i have

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :home_team, :away_team, :fixture_date, :kickoff_time, :prediction_id

  has_many :predictions
end

class Prediction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :home_team, :away_team, :home_score, :away_score, :fixture_date, :fixture_id, :user_id

 has_many :fixtures
end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :home_team, :away_team, :score, :fixture_date
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :prediction_id

has_many :predictions
end

class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :result_id, :score, :user_id, :prediction_id
end
```

So my thinking at the moment is that i could do some comparisons in the Point model as i can access the predictions and results? maybe a case statement so that when the prediction and result match then allocate the value 3. afterwhich i could then save that value to the Point model.

Second option I was thinking is a rake task that updates the Point model

A problem i can see at the moment is that a prediction score gets assigned using separate values, ie home_score and away_score as integers and the result score is stored as a string, ie 2-2.This is governed by the way i am scraping the data.

How would someone with more experience approach this?, looking to learn a few things here.

Any advice appreciated

Thank you

Edit

I have come up with this, though probably very wrong, this is how i invisige the logic?

```
def points_total
  points = case 
  when predition.home_score && prediction.away_score == result.home_score && result.away_score
    self.score = 3
  when prediction.home_score == result.home_score || prediction.away_score == result.away_score
    self.score = 1
  when prediction.home_score != result.home_score && prediction.away_score != result.away_scor
    self.score = 0
  end
end

def allocate_points
  points_total
  Point.create!(points: score)

end
```

with regards to splitting the score string into two integers this can be done

```
left, right =  "4x3".split("x").map(&:to_i)
```

so in my case would it be

```
home_result, away_result = Result.score.split("x").map(&:to_i)
```

Im gathering bits and pieces trying to figure this out but not even sure if going in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

This came into my mind reading your question, let's say the following is in the `Prediction` model:

```
def points_total
  wrong_predictions = [home_score - result.home_score, away_score - home.away_score]
  wrong_predictions = wrong_predictions.reject { |i| i == 0 }.size # returns 0, 1 or 2
  case wrong_predictions
  when 0 then 3
  when 1 then 1
  else 0
  end
end
```

Here's an even shorter example, although less readable maybe:

```
def wrong_predictions
  [home_score - result.home_score, away_score - home.away_score].reject { |i| i == 0 }.size
end

def points_total
  [3,1,0][wrong_predictions]
end
```

I'm not sure however how a prediction is associated to a result.

When saving the points you should associate them to something. Also you must use `score` as an attribute since that's the column you have in the points table, not `points`.

```
def allocate_points
  points.create!(score: points_total)
  # or create_point(...) or whatever
end
```

#### Update: method explained

The first part of the method

```
[home_score - result.home_score, away_score - home.away_score]
```

subtracts the real results from the user's predicted results, so if he predicted correctly it will add up to 0, otherwise a positive or negative integer. So if he guess both correctly the array would be `[0, 0]`, if he missed one by 2 points then something like `[0, 2]`, or both wrong `[-1, 1]` .

Next we delete all zeros from the array with `reject { |i| i == 0 }`, so the previous arrays would look like `[]`, `[2]` and `[-1, 1]`.

Calling `size` on the array tells us how many objects are in the array (in this case how many wrong predictions the user made), so from the above `0`, `1` and `2`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, im unsure what the method wrong_predictions is doing though? could you elaborate please?

Comment: thank you, so to make sure i am understanding correctly, the points model still holds points allocated.. the logic for working out how many points are allocated gets done in the prediction model.With regards to showing the points earned by a user would a user have_many points through predicitons?

Comment: Yeah I guess it would make sense to create a `Prediction has_one :point` association (I'm guessing each prediction is for a single game so there would be only 1 result). You could put that code in the `Point` model instead, it depends on how you want to call it. I'm not sure what is the more "correct" way.

Comment: actually thinking about it if multiple users are making predictions should i use Prediction has_many :points

Comment: Not if a user has many predictions. Then if a user has 5 predictions, he can have 5 points. Each user has his own predictions right?

Comment: ah i see what you mean now, the points can be accessed via the prediction model, which a user has many of...

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that home_team, away_team and fixture_date are repeated in the Fixture, Prediction and Result table, my advice is:

- Create a 'football_game' that has those three attributes
- Create other attribute for it as needed such as score
- Create other models such as Prediction with a reference to the football_match instance (row) using `football_match_id`.  I am staying away from just 'match' as that is such a generic term and in ruby you can do "gfgfgffg.match("g").  Not a reserved word per se but I would avoid.  Naming is incredibly important.

Do this step and try to get it working for simple stuff in the `script/rails console`.  Try to create objects in the console and then create associated objects (both using `Class.new` where Class is football_game or Prediction, etc.)

After that... see how it looks and think about the next step **then**

Comment: thank you for your explanation, would you mind elaborating on that please, struggling to get my head around this..S

Comment: I recommend an agile approach.  First get that working (I expanded the answer a bit) in the console, then address the next steps after that.  First thing is to have models that aren't repeating all those fields.  The full solution will take some work and maybe several SO questions for each stage.  Take it slowly for a better result :)

Comment: yes this is very in depth, so taking it a step at a time is definitely  a good idea, plus by doing it stages i will hopefully  learn a lot more